# How to convert common js to ES6 modules?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, import, require, ecmascript-5

I know that there are many solutions to convert es6 to js. but when I was searching, I didn't find any solution converting js to es6! in my case I really need to convert this code to es6:

```
const m3o = require("m3o")(process.env.M3O_API_TOKEN);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with m3o, but my ES6 translation of what you posted would be:

```
import { default as m3o } from 'm3o';
m3o(process.env.M3O_API_TOKEN);
```

Comment: `import m3o from 'm3o'` should also work.

Comment: Yeah, `import m3o from 'm3o';` is shorter, but I always do it like above. I forget why. @FelixKling